# Are there standard 8-bit color palettes?

Tags: colors, binaryfiles, color-palette

I'm attempting to reverse engineer a file format from a logging program.  It seems to use a 1-2 byte field which may be used for label colors, as it seems to be the only thing that's unexplained.  Short of iterating through other label colors and generating new output files (which is a pain in the ass, hence me trying to reverse-engineer the format in the first place), are there any standard 8-bit color palettes they may line up with?  I've found some (e.g. the only 216 colors that are allowed on the web), but they're not enumerated in any particular way.

I believe `0x32` is light green (e.g. 0,255,0), `0x0A` is <strike>teal</strike> *cyan* (0, 255, 255), and `0x28` is red.  Each field may also include a trailing `0x00`.

Or I could be totally wrong.

Comment: Just being a stickler here, but (0, 255, 255) is cyan :) That being said, +1 because I'm curious about the answer, too.

Comment: Have you considered that a palette may be embedded in the file format itself (It's not a given, but it's worth looking)?  You could also enumerate several consecutive indexes to see if there is any pattern you could fill out procedurally.

Comment: I've explained away all the major blocks in the file, and nothing seems like a nice sequential palette entry.  These values could very well be something proprietary, but an answer to the general question would be interesting.

Answer (score 10):

Well, it could be one of the old standard VGA palettes.  This is the one for mode 13h:

[image]

However, the numbers you posted seem to be off-by-one from the index into the usual ordering.

EDIT:  Here are the 24-bit RGB values for the color components in a python formatted array.  It is a bit long so be warned!

> [0x000000, 0x0000a8, 0x00a800, 0x00a8a8, 0xa80000, 0xa800a8, 0xa85400, 0xa8a8a8, 0x545454, 0x5454fc, 0x54fc54, 0x54fcfc, 0xfc5454, 0xfc54fc, 0xfcfc54, 0xfcfcfc, 0x000000, 0x141414, 0x202020, 0x2c2c2c, 0x383838, 0x444444, 0x505050, 0x606060, 0x707070, 0x808080, 0x909090, 0xa0a0a0, 0xb4b4b4, 0xc8c8c8, 0xe0e0e0, 0xfcfcfc, 0x0000fc, 0x4000fc, 0x7c00fc, 0xbc00fc, 0xfc00fc, 0xfc00bc, 0xfc007c, 0xfc0040, 0xfc0000, 0xfc4000, 0xfc7c00, 0xfcbc00, 0xfcfc00, 0xbcfc00, 0x7cfc00, 0x40fc00, 0x00fc00, 0x00fc40, 0x00fc7c, 0x00fcbc, 0x00fcfc, 0x00bcfc, 0x007cfc, 0x0040fc, 0x7c7cfc, 0x9c7cfc, 0xbc7cfc, 0xdc7cfc, 0xfc7cfc, 0xfc7cdc, 0xfc7cbc, 0xfc7c9c, 0xfc7c7c, 0xfc9c7c, 0xfcbc7c, 0xfcdc7c, 0xfcfc7c, 0xdcfc7c, 0xbcfc7c, 0x9cfc7c, 0x7cfc7c, 0x7cfc9c, 0x7cfcbc, 0x7cfcdc, 0x7cfcfc, 0x7cdcfc, 0x7cbcfc, 0x7c9cfc, 0xb4b4fc, 0xc4b4fc, 0xd8b4fc, 0xe8b4fc, 0xfcb4fc, 0xfcb4e8, 0xfcb4d8, 0xfcb4c4, 0xfcb4b4, 0xfcc4b4, 0xfcd8b4, 0xfce8b4, 0xfcfcb4, 0xe8fcb4, 0xd8fcb4, 0xc4fcb4, 0xb4fcb4, 0xb4fcc4, 0xb4fcd8, 0xb4fce8, 0xb4fcfc, 0xb4e8fc, 0xb4d8fc, 0xb4c4fc, 0x000070, 0x1c0070, 0x380070, 0x540070, 0x700070, 0x700054, 0x700038, 0x70001c, 0x700000, 0x701c00, 0x703800, 0x705400, 0x707000, 0x547000, 0x387000, 0x1c7000, 0x007000, 0x00701c, 0x007038, 0x007054, 0x007070, 0x005470, 0x003870, 0x001c70, 0x383870, 0x443870, 0x543870, 0x603870, 0x703870, 0x703860, 0x703854, 0x703844, 0x703838, 0x704438, 0x705438, 0x706038, 0x707038, 0x607038, 0x547038, 0x447038, 0x387038, 0x387044, 0x387054, 0x387060, 0x387070, 0x386070, 0x385470, 0x384470, 0x505070, 0x585070, 0x605070, 0x685070, 0x705070, 0x705068, 0x705060, 0x705058, 0x705050, 0x705850, 0x706050, 0x706850, 0x707050, 0x687050, 0x607050, 0x587050, 0x507050, 0x507058, 0x507060, 0x507068, 0x507070, 0x506870, 0x506070, 0x505870, 0x000040, 0x100040, 0x200040, 0x300040, 0x400040, 0x400030, 0x400020, 0x400010, 0x400000, 0x401000, 0x402000, 0x403000, 0x404000, 0x304000, 0x204000, 0x104000, 0x004000, 0x004010, 0x004020, 0x004030, 0x004040, 0x003040, 0x002040, 0x001040, 0x202040, 0x282040, 0x302040, 0x382040, 0x402040, 0x402038, 0x402030, 0x402028, 0x402020, 0x402820, 0x403020, 0x403820, 0x404020, 0x384020, 0x304020, 0x284020, 0x204020, 0x204028, 0x204030, 0x204038, 0x204040, 0x203840, 0x203040, 0x202840, 0x2c2c40, 0x302c40, 0x342c40, 0x3c2c40, 0x402c40, 0x402c3c, 0x402c34, 0x402c30, 0x402c2c, 0x40302c, 0x40342c, 0x403c2c, 0x40402c, 0x3c402c, 0x34402c, 0x30402c, 0x2c402c, 0x2c4030, 0x2c4034, 0x2c403c, 0x2c4040, 0x2c3c40, 0x2c3440, 0x2c3040, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000]

Comment: Is there some list for the indices of that image to the RGB values?  Other than that, off-by-one is an easy fix, and could make sense as black may well be an invalid color.

Answer (score -1):

There is no standard palette for 8-bit **but** Teletext uses true 8-bit color palette

It's based on hardwares

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_8-bit_computer_hardware_palettes

Edit : Some devices able to show different shades of color by adjusting brightness but true 8-bit is this palette ( [Teletext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_8-bit_computer_hardware_palettes#Teletext) )

[image]

Comment: The article says it's an *8-color*, 3-bit palette

Comment: combination of those 3 bit with give you 8 color , true 8-bit color is what you will see , any other color is shades which adjusted by brightness of hardware

Comment: This is a 4 bit pp indexed image.